# JavaScript: how to handle all the errors except ones which can be produced by mistype

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

Consider a code sample:

```
const someThing = { f: function() {} }
try {
    something.f() // there is a mistype
} catch(e) {
    // some error handling specific to function f
}
```

So, I want to not handle all the errors which can be produced by my mistype like: `ReferenceError`, `TypeError` and also I don't want to handle `AssertionError`.

Is there any idiomatic way to do that?

Comment: Do you want JavaScript to recognize programmer mistakes and real runtime errors?

Comment: I want to have a catch handler which catches all the types of errors except: ReferenceError, TypeError and AssertionError. In case of such error the program should just fail

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand. - If you want to deal with errors generated in `something.f()` but want to ignore other errors then don't use `catch` or error handlers. I'm assuming you want to catch errors in regards to `business logic` when executing `something.f()` - If not, ignore my comment :) - If so however, separate errors from business rule violations and have `something.f()` deal with it's own rule checks internally and when a business rule is broken populate a `violations` object you can either return or query after execution. I never use `catch` but only deal with what I want to.

Comment: Just to add, if you however do want to catch unexpected errors that can occur in `something.f()` I would recommend not to. Never deal with unexpected errors IMHO they always should break the flow horribly as they are unexpected and should not occur to begin with. I know `TryParse` logic and similar work by catching exceptions but even those are dealing with expected failures :) In the long run dealing with unexpected errors leads to potentially hiding them by accident, causing issues in your code to become invisible.

Comment: @Fran I completely agree with you point of you. The question is how to write the catch handler which doesn't catch all the errors?

If `f` is written by me, it's easy: I just need to create a type of error which is specific for f(e.g. `FError`:) ). but What should I do in the situation when `f` is third party code and it throws  Error(e.g. superagent throws Error in case of 404)

Comment: @kharandziuk When consuming third party code you have to rely on them having tested their own code and IMHO you should let the code blow up. However, you could create a third-party-wrapper `somethingWrapper` that deals with `something` specific issues. That way you can inspect all errors in isolation and have your wrapper return managed violations or raise other errors you like to catch such as `FError`, calling `somethingWrapper.f() ` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```js
var ignoredErrors = [TypeError, ReferenceError];

function handleError (e) {
  for (var index in ignoredErrors) {
    if (e instanceof ignoredErrors[index]) {
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log('A "real" error occured:', e.message);
}

const someThing = { f: function() {} }
try {
  something.f(); // ReferenceError: ignored
} catch(e) {
  handleError(e);
}

try {
  eval('()'); // SyntaxError: not ignored
} catch(e) {
  handleError(e);
}
```

But do you really want to have that? Do you want to ignore your mistakes instead of solving the errors in your program?